# jQuery - on click scrollTop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to scroll down to a div #drawer on click but nothing happens.The rest of my function works normally, it just won't scroll. This is my code:

Html:

```
            <img
              src="/imagecache/large/{{ $issue->first()->image  }}"
              onclick="{{ $function }}(
                '{{ $issue->first()->magazine->id }}',
                '{{ $issue->first()->magazine->name }}',
                '{{ $issue->first()->magazine->summary ?: '' }}',
                '{{ $issue->first()->magazine->image ?: '' }}',
                '{{ $issue->first()->image  }}'
                )"
              >
```

And script:

```
function magazineDetail(id, name, summary, issueImage, magazineImage)

{
    images = [];
    nextImage = 0;
    loadedImages = [];

    $('#name').text(name);
    $('#summary').text(summary);
    $('#cover-image').attr({"src" : '/imagecache/cover/' + magazineImage, "alt" : name});

    if (issueImage != '') {
      $('#issueImage').html('<img src="/imagecache/medium/"' + issueImage + ' alt="' + name + '">');
    }

    $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#magazine-detail").offset().top
    });

    $.getJSON("issue/images",
        { id: id },
        function(result){
          if (result.length < 2){
              $('.magazine-preview-nav').hide();
          } else {
              $('.magazine-preview-nav').show();
          }
          $.each(result, function(i, value){
              images.push(value);
          });
          function imagePreload() {
              preload();
          };
    });
}
```

This is my html structure:

```
         <div id="app">
            <div id="bg">
            </div>

              @section('topBar')
                @include('customer.layouts.partials.top-bar')
              @show
            <div id="main-section">
              @section('header')
                @include('customer.layouts.partials.header')
              @show

              @section('carousel')
                @include('customer.layouts.partials.carousel', ['function' => 'magazineDetail', 'carouselPadding' => ''])
              @show
            </div>


            <div id="drawer">
              <div id="magazine-detail">
                @section('magazine-detail')
                  @include('customer.layouts.partials.magazine-detail')
                @show
              </div>
              <div id="magazine-detail-carousel">
                @section('magazine-detail-carousel')
                  @include('customer.layouts.partials.carousel', ['function' => 'magazineDetail', 'carouselPadding' => 'carouselPadding'])
                @show
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And css:

```
#main-section {
  top: 92px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#drawer {
  height: calc(100vh - 92px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: $white;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

When I do

```
console.log($("#magazine-detail").offset().top);
```

It gives me the correct value, which was in my case 967

**Update**

I managed to get it working with this:

```
$('#drawer')[0].scrollIntoView( false );
```

Comment: maybe inspector console has some info?

Comment: I'm not JQuery master, try adding console log, to your "magazineDetail" function. Just to separate working things from not working.

Comment: no errors in the console

Comment: I have other stuff in the function as well which all are working

Comment: `console.log($("#magazine-detail").offset().top)` gives you what?

Comment: if the presented HTML is the only elements you have then the reason why your scroll is not working is because you are trying to access elements that don't exist. Look here, our scroll is working https://jsfiddle.net/1v4p3qtw/

Comment: @Leff SO if you were to comment out the other code in that function and just leave the animate line, does it work? Also what browser are you using?

Comment: It is still not working when I comment out the rest of the code, I have tested it in safari and chrome